# Using "rm" to remove files remotely from another directory?

Tags: command-line, terminal

I'm unable to use the rm command to remove files remotely from another directory. I'm a beginner so I apologise for my inability to elaborate properly.

Here's what I'm trying to do: 
I'm trying to delete all .srt files from a sub directory. It works when I cd into the specific directory like so:

Command 1: 
cd /users/jakubdonovan/library/cloudstorage/iCloud\ drive/the-modern-python3-bootcamp/target_folder

Command 2: 
rm *.srt

However, let's say I want to quickly delete a specific file type from a folder without first using the "cd" command, like so:

rm *.srt /users/jakubdonovan/library/cloudstorage/iCloud\ drive/the-modern-python3-bootcamp/target_folder

It returns with "No matches for wildcard '*.srt'. See `help expand`."

Which is strange because I can use the touch, cp and and all the other commands remotely without a problem.

Is there a way to make the command "rm *.filetype" remove all the files with that specific filetype from a folder and all its subfolders in one swoop?

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to rm in a sub-directory you just have to specify that sub-directory in the command.

```
rm /path/to/folder/*.filetype
```

or if you know that the folder is inside your current directory you can try...

```
rm ./folder/*.filetype
```

Comment: 'Ask Ubuntu' may be a better place to ask questions like this, didn't want to put that in my answer though.